# Deleting file contents from FTP Server using shell

Tags: linux, shell

I just want to know, If is there any possibility to delete some lines of a .txt file on the FTP Server without down and uploading it using a shell script? If yes then please help me with the steps.

Comment: Nope it is called **File Transfer Protocol** for a reason - it transfers files rather than providing any facilities to edit them.

Comment: Not explicitly no. You'd have to modify the file remotely and then replace. Can you tell me why this is necessary? There may be another workaround.